# Identifying groups with better response to treatment

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, sas, control-group

We have tested a population (splitted in test 50% and control 50%) with a treatment. Overall, the treatment was effective - our test variable was significantly different in the treatment and control averages.

But how to find out if there is an age group, or income group, where it was more effective? I can do multiple analysis by hand (splitting the population by age, or income), but I was wondering if there is some automated (machine learning) way of identifying groups with better response to the treatment.

If there is an automated way in Python or SAS?

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear how you found that:

> Overall, the treatment was effective

Assuming that you fitted a simple regression model in SAS:

```
PROC REG DATA=your_data;
MODEL response = treatment;
RUN;
```

then you can simply add variables for age and income and interact them with treatment.

```
PROC REG DATA=your_data;
MODEL response = treatment age income treatment*age treatment*income;
RUN;
```